# $ is not a function error while using vTicker JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, smarty

I am trying to implement JQuery vTicker on my website. I am loading the Jquery in header :

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.vticker.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

**also have put this script tag in header :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">{literal}$(function() {$("#myclass").vTicker({
speed: 500,pause: 3000,animation: 'fade',mousePause: false,showItems: 3});});{/literal</script>
```

**However I am getting following error :**

```
$("#myclass").vTicker is not a function
  showItems: 3
```

Any help/tip would be highly appreciated. link to the site :
http://67.20.122.201/boikeno/home.php

The site uses Smarty and PHP

Comment: you just need one version of jQuery. you don't need to include two versions of it. use the latest.

Comment: @joseph removed the redundant JQueries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to include the full jquery library, the vticker file is just a plugin.

Edit:

Took a closer look at your page.  You've got all sorts of craziness going on... you've defined two DOCTYPEs, two <head> blocks, and you include vticker before you include jquery.  All of that should be cleaned up, but the main thing getting in your way here appears to be that you need to include jquery before you include vticker.

Comment: included JQuery before Vticker but no better

Comment: It seems cleaning up the crap helped :)

Comment: Glad that worked for you.  I find that often cleaning up my code does wonders.

Answer (score 1):

You are including three versions of jQuery in your page, which is causing the error. Remove the reference to 1.6 and 1.4.4 (the one you are hosting)

You are currently including:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js

and

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js

and

http://67.20.122.201/boikeno/assets/js/jquery.min.js

Comment: removed the 2 older versions of JQuery.. still no change

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery library also. because the plugin is making use of jQuery functions.

Your head section should be like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.vticker.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

And your page has 2 reference to two different versions of jQuery. only one ( latest stable) is enough.

Comment: The Vticker Jquery I am using is here : http://67.20.122.201/boikeno/assets/js/jquery.vticker.js